# Relation For The Function Of Orientations Of A Die

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

"Take a 6-sided die and place it on your desk with one side facing
you. Each possible orientation defines a function from $\{front, back, left, right, top, bottom\}$ to ${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}$. $f(x)$ is the
number that is showing on face $x$. Let $S$ be the set of all such functions.

Define a relation ∼ on S by $f$ ∼ $g$ ⇔ $f(top) = g(top)$. In other words, ~ is a relation on the set of all possible die orientations; orientations are related if they share the same number on the top face.

Prove that this is an equivalence relation."

**Work So Far**

The actual proof for this is relatively simple; I can define$front_0 = a, back_0=b, left_0=c, right_0=d, top_0=e, bottom_0 = f.$ Then just establish that $top_0=top_{90}=top_{180}=top_{270}$, $left_0 = right_{180}$, etc.

The difficulty I'm running into is figuring out exactly how this function is supposed to be represented. At first glance, it seems to me like it should be a set of 6 ordered pairs, a sample for one orientation would be:

$\{(front,5),(back,2),(left,3),(right,4),(top,1),(bottom,6)\}$

The problem is, it's impossible for a relation made from 4 of these functions to be equivalent; you're never going to get the point $(5, front)$, for example, which would be required to show symmetry with $(front, 5)$. So clearly, I'm representing it wrong, but am not sure about the correct alternative. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The relation $\sim$ is a relation among the orientation functions themselves, not among the ordered pairs that make up those functions.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't really seem representable either. If $\{(front,5),(back,2),(left,3),(right,4),(top,1),(bottom,6)\}$ is called "$\{1 rotated 0\}$," for example, then the relation is $R = \{1 rotated 0, 1 rotated 90, 1 rotated 180, 1 rotated 270\}$. How can this possibly be demonstrated to have symmetry, reflexivity, and transitivity?

Comment: No, a relation is a set of ordered pairs, in this case $\{(1\text{rot}0,1\text{rot}0),(1\text{rot}0,1\text{rot}90),(1\text{rot}180),\dots,(1\text{rot}90,1\text{rot}0),\dots,(2\text{rot}0,2\text{rot}0),(2\text{rot}0,2\text{rot}90),\dots\}$.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh you're absolutely right, this is where I'm going wrong! Thank you, I was mixing terminology up in my head. Suddenly this all makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 24 orientations in this scheme, four for each number that can appear at the top of the die, but I don’t think that’s really directly relevant. It seems to me that $\sim$ being an equivalence relation is a simple consequence of equality being an equivalence relation. Take symmetry, for instance. If $f\sim g$, this means that $f(\text{top})=g(\text{top})$. By symmetry of equality, $g(\text{top})=f(\text{top})$ and so $g\sim f$. Can you prove reflexivity and transitivity now?

Comment: Is this really a proof, though? It seems like "$f(\text{top})=g(\text{top})$ therefore $g(\text{top})=f(\text{top})$" is just stating what "equals" means. Same for "$f(\text{top})=g(\text{top}) = g(\text{top})=f(\text{top}) = f(\text{top})=g(\text{top})$ therefore $f(\text{top})=f(\text{top})$" for reflexivity. It's correct, but is that really an adequate proof?

Comment: @Chase What else do you think you might need, or even use? Orientation similarity is defined entirely via equality of the top faces, so it inherits being an equivalence relation from that. There’s really nothing else to work with here.

Comment: @Chase Suppose instead that orientation similarity were defined as ”the top faces have the same parity.” You’d use the fact that this is an equivalence relation in the same way to show that orientation similarity is one, too.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. amd has cleared up the relation format, and this used to create the proof. Thank you both for the help, I'll accept this answer when possible.